# Обратное событие для on_ready

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

В discord.py есть функция - событие on_ready

```py
async def on_ready():
    ...
```

У меня вопрос к знатокам фреймворка discord.py - существует ли событие обратное данному, например on_disconnect или тому подобное?

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду, что событие должно срабатывать, когда бот "выключается", то такого нет.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.